# how to pick a value in order from 1 to 10

Tags: c#, selenium

am working with C# and Selenium and I need to send keys into a text field it would need to pick a `name` (the names I provide into a textbox) and then pick then send the first one (with send keys)
after its done with the first one it would move to the second and so on.
I have done this so far (but this would randomly pick a name and not in a order way from first to last)

```
var random = new Random();

//this is the textbox in which I place the "names"\\
        var Names = question1.Text.Split();

        int index = random.Next(Names.Length);

        string randomName = Names[index];`
```

this would just pick a random value I place into a textbox so I will need that but the issue with this is if am sending lets say 100 names after 25/50 the names would just start to be duplicates which led to an error so thats why I need it to select the names in order.

Comment: _I need to send keys into a text field...pick a name (the names I provide into a textbox)_:  Can you elaborate more?

Comment: so lets say in the text box i place the following names: david jack john kevin eren. i want to be able to send "david" first and then "jack" and the "john" and so on and not just randomly pick one of the names since that after a while would lead to duplicates. those this make sense?

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't just iterate over the `Names` array, e.g., using a `for` or a `foreach` loop?

Comment: i just stared using C# so i dont know much yet but another thing is that i would need to send a name and fill a form and then re-start the procedure from the second name

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to use the shuffle algorithm first and then create a queue of shuffled names:

```
var shuffledNames = question1.Text.Split().OrderBy(_ => Guid.NewGuid());
var queueOfShuffledNames = new Queue<string>(shuffledNames);
        
Console.WriteLine($"Queue of shuffled names: {string.Join(", ", queueOfShuffledNames)}");
Console.WriteLine($"Selected name: {queueOfShuffledNames.Dequeue()}");
Console.WriteLine($"Queue of shuffled names: {string.Join(", ", queueOfShuffledNames)}");
```

Link: https://dotnetfiddle.net/9Hfkbt

If you need to remove duplication from the original collection and limit the number of items in the queue, create the `shuffledNames` this way:

```
var shuffledNames = question1.Text.Split()
    .OrderBy(_ => Guid.NewGuid())
    .Distinct()
    .Take(10);
```

Comment: but i need to fill the names into a 'textbox' and not into the actual code it self

Comment: @goldenleo just replace my array `new[] { "name1", ... }` with getting names from the textbox

Comment: i done it like this but it gives me an error. "var shuffledNames = question1..Text.Split();" ans also for sending keys what should i put into the send keys function? i have done it like this "driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("name")).SendKeys(shuffledNames);"

Answer (score -1):

I think you can add all the names in `Hashset` and then using `for` loop you can pick names one by one

Comment: how would i integrate that? into my code.

Comment: `HashSet<string> names = new HashSet<string>();`
`names.Add("name1"`
`names.Add("name2")`

`foreach(string name in names)
{
      textField.SendKeys(name) //textField is your textbox element
 }`

Comment: there is a couple of errors it says that string does not contain the defeniton of ADD and for foreach CANNOT CONVERT CHAR TO STIRNG any help please

Comment: Could you share your complete code?